# Odoo Server Conf SyntaxError Centos 6.9

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10, odoo-view

Yesterday I installed Odoo in Centos 6.9
PostgreSql Successfully Installed and running
Odoo successfully Installed but when I start odoo service Error Occured

```
[root@inj ~]# service odoo start
Starting Odoo Server Daemon (odoo-server): [ OK ]
[root@inj ~]# File "", line 1
/etc/odoo-server.conf
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

and here is my conf File

```
[options]
admin_passwd = *****************************
db_host = localhost
db_port = 5432
db_user = odoo
db_password = *****************************
addons_path = /opt/odoo/addons
load = web
timezone = Asia/Dubai
without-demo=all
logfile = /var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log
log_handler = werkzeug:WARNING
log_level = warn
no-logrotate = True
```

[Check Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5GA3.png)

Answer (score 0):

The options on the config file should not have dashes but underscores. So try `without_demo = True` and `logrotate = False` and isntead of `load = web` try `server_wide_modules = web`

Also make sure that every option that you have set is valid, you can see the valid options [here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/3ace806d399e9e3abc5ada84ba98d2de100388d3/odoo/tools/config.py#L98). Check the `dest` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. i made changes but still i get same error.

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan post the contents of your service file

Comment: [options]
addons_path = /opt/odoo/addons
admin_passwd = ****************
db_host = localhost
db_port = 5432
db_user = odoo
db_password = ****************
logfile = /var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log